# How to raise custom Postgresql error and handle it in Ecto

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I created a custom function in Postgresql that checks data before insert or update and raises error if something goes wrong.

```
CREATE FUNCTION custom_check() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF <SOME CONDITION> THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'CUSTOM ERROR';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
""")
```

When I'm using constraints in Postgresql, I can handle errors raised with `Ecto.Changeset.check_constraint`.

But I didn't find a way to handle this error I'm raising, to reflect it in changeset instead of getting an exception and probably catching it inside my code.

Should I raise error differently for `Ecto.Changeset.check_constraint` to handle it, or do differently something else?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I don't think there is a built-in method of handling trigger errors, so you might end up manually rescuing it in your function call and adding the error to your changeset.

Comment: I changed exception to `RAISE EXCEPTION 'CUSTOM ERROR', USING ERRCODE = 'check_violation';,` but Ecto still doesn't like catching it. I'm catching it in tests using `assert_raise(Postgrex.Error, ~R/CUSTOM ERROR/`. And yes, I will probably end up catching it in my Elixir code.

Comment: Why do you run logic (condition checks) on DB level instead of Elixir function?

Comment: Because it's more robust. Gives me 100% guarantee that nothing will go wrong.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is no built-in mechanism for handling custom PostgreSQL's errors. However, you can do it at the repository level.

To do that, you have to raise errors in the PostgreSQL using `ERRCODE` like:

```
RAISE '[message for logs]' USING ERRCODE = 'integrity_constraint_violation';
```

and then handle them in the application:

```
defmodule Core.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :core

  defoverridable insert: 2

  def insert(changeset, opts) do
    super(changeset, opts)
  rescue
    exception in Postgrex.Error ->
      handle_postgrex_exception(exception, __STACKTRACE__, changeset)
  end

  # ... other functions

  defp handle_postgrex_exception(exception, stacktrace, changeset \\ nil)

  defp handle_postgrex_exception(%{postgres: %{code: :integrity_constraint_violation}}, _, nil) do
    {:error, :integrity_constraint_violation}
  end

  defp handle_postgrex_exception(
         %{postgres: %{code: :integrity_constraint_violation}},
         _,
         changeset
       ) do
    {:error, %{changeset | valid?: false}}
  end

  defp handle_postgrex_exception(exception, stacktrace, _) do
    reraise(exception, stacktrace)
  end
end
```

Note the `{:error, %{changeset | valid?: false}}` response. It means that at that point, there won't be any useful message to display.

PS you could probably write some macros to override Ecto's functions and hide the implementation there (instead of the proposed solution) but I believe it would be much harder to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to intercept trigger raised errors within a changeset. The method is to disguise your error as one of the constraints that is already implemented by the Postgres Ecto adapter:

1. :unique_violation
2. :foreign_key_violation
3. :exclusion_violation
4. :check_violation

In order to do that, you need to raise error in your PLSQL function in the following way:

```sql
 RAISE EXCEPTION 'CUSTOM ERROR' USING ERRCODE = 'check_violation', CONSTRAINT = 'name_of your_contraint';
```

where `ERRCODE` is one from the above list, and `CONSTRAINT` is custom.

in your code:

```plsql
CREATE FUNCTION custom_check() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF <SOME CONDITION> THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'CUSTOM ERROR' 
        USING ERRCODE = 'check_violation', 
        CONSTRAINT = 'name_of_your_contraint';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

and then in your changeset:

```elixir
def changeset(schema, attrs) do
   schema
   |> check_constraint(:some_field, name: name_of_your_contraint: , message: "custom error message")
end
```