# With Ecto, validate that a changeset with 2 different related models have the same parent model

Tags: validation, elixir, ecto, changeset

In my app I have a method to create a new `response`. A `response` has a `belongs_to` relationship to both a `player` and `match`.

In addition `player` and `match` both have a `belongs_to` relationship to a `team`.

It looks like this:

[image: schema]

When inserting a new `response` I want to validate that the `player` and `match` having the `player_id` and `match_id` foreign keys in the changeset belong to the same `team`.

Currently I'm achieving this as follows. First, define a custom validation that checks the records belonging to the foreign keys:

```
def validate_match_player(changeset) do
  player_team =
    Player
    |> Repo.get(get_field(changeset, :player_id))
    |> Map.get(:team_id)

  match_team =
    Match
    |> Repo.get(get_field(changeset, :match_id))
    |> Map.get(:team_id)

  cond do
    match_team == player_team -> changeset
    true -> changeset |> add_error(:player, "does not belong to the same team as the match")
  end
end
```

and the use the validation as part of the changeset:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
  model
  |> cast(params, [:player_id, :match_id, :message])
  |> validate_required([:player_id, :match_id, :message])
  |> foreign_key_constraint(:match_id)
  |> foreign_key_constraint(:player_id)
  |> validate_match_player()
  |> unique_constraint(
    :player,
    name: :responses_player_id_match_id_unique,
    message: "already has an response for this match"
  )
end
```

This works fine but involves a couple of extra SQL queries to look up the related records in order to get their `team_id` foreign keys to compare them.

Is there a nicer way to do this, perhaps using constraints, that avoids the extra queries?

Comment: AFAIK, a constraint can't access other table's data. So either write a trigger in SQL that prevents the edit when that condition isn't met or leave it like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two possible improvements:

- Application level solution: instead of two queries, you just query once.
- Database level solution: you create a trigger for the check in the database.

## Application Level Solution

Right now you have two queries for checking that player and match belong to the same team. That means two round trips to the database. You could reduce this by half if you use just one query e.g. given the following query:

```sql
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM players AS p
INNER JOIN matches AS m
        ON p.team_id = m.team_id
     WHERE p.id = NEW.player_id AND m.id = NEW.match_id
```

you would change your function as follows:

```
def validate_match_player(changeset) do
  player_id = get_field(changeset, :player_id)
  match_id = get_field(changeset, :match_id)

  [result] =
    Player
    |> join(:inner, [p], m in Match, on: p.team_id == m.team_id)
    |> where([p, m], p.id == ^player_id and m.id == ^match_id)
    |> select([p, m], %{count: count(p.id)})
    |> Repo.all()

  case result do
    %{count: 0} ->
      add_error(changeset, :player, "does not belong to the same team as the match")
    _ ->
      changeset
  end
end
```

## Database Level Solution

I'm assuming you're using PostgreSQL, so my answer will correspond to what you can find in the PostgreSQL manual.

There's no (clean) way to define a constraint in the table that does this. Constraints can only access the table where they're defined. Some constraints can only access the column from what they're defined and nothing more (`CHECK CONSTRAINT`).

The best approach would be writing a trigger for validating both fields e.g:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_validate_match_player()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    IF (
         SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM players AS p
         INNER JOIN matches AS m
         ON p.team_id = m.team_id
         WHERE p.id = NEW.player_id AND m.id = NEW.match_id
       ) = 0
    THEN
      RAISE 'does not belong to the same team as the match'
        USING ERRCODE 'invalid_match_player';
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER responses_validate_match_player
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON responses
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_validate_match_player();
```

The previous trigger will raise an exception when it fails. This also means Ecto will raise an exception. You can see how to handle this exception [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53259205/4776680).

In the end, maintaining triggers is not easy unless you're using something like [sqitch](https://sqitch.org/) for database migrations.

> PS: If you're curious, the **very** dirty way of doing this in a `CHECK` constraint is by defining a PostgreSQL function that basically bypasses the limitation. I wouldn't recommend it.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: nice answer thanks! I think your point around difficulty maintaining triggers is valid. I did think about a single query with a join and this looks like the way to go.